# NuGet package restore with Mono on Travis CI failing

Tags: c#, .net, mono, nuget, travis-ci

[My project](https://github.com/rexm/SimpleDb.Net) compiles & runs fine on OSX and Windows. However, trying to get it hooked up to Travis CI, I get this error from NuGet (using version 2.8):

> [Could not load type 'NuGet.MSBuildProjectUtility' from assembly 'NuGet, Version=2.8.50126.400, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.](https://travis-ci.org/rexm/SimpleDb.Net/builds/19548639#L838)

Not really sure what to think about this one... MSBuildProjectUtility is obviously present in the assembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Mono version is very old, the project built fine for me on Mono 3.2.1.

<strike>To get a more recent version you can use this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~directhex/+archive/monoxide.</strike>

Add it to your system with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:directhex/monoxide && sudo apt-get update`. Then you can install Mono with `sudo apt-get install mono-devel`.

Xamarin now ships official Mono packages for Linux, so the PPA isn't necessary anymore. See http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/ for the installation guide.

Note: in order for Mono to verify SSL connections, you also need to import certificates with `mozroots --import --sync`, otherwise downloading packages from nuget.org will fail.

Comment: I am also using Mono 3.2.1 via apt-get. I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Ah, actually, I see it seems like Travis is pulling down an older version than I expected. I've got 3.2.1 locally via the same. Wonder why Travis is different...

Comment: Because the standard dist for Ubuntu is still 2.10 :| blah. I see where you're going now.

Comment: OK, I am a little slow but I eventually got what you're saying. Got it sorted, it's working now! Thanks!